# Rect Position doesn't reset if animation is canceled

Tags: unity, animation, gui, mecanim

I have a text component that displays a text with an animation. If I disable the GameObject while the animation is running, the Rect Transform doesn't reset to the original position, which makes the text appear revealed next time it has to come. How can I fix this?

This is how the settings look like:

[image]

Comment: Is the text rect or it's parent holding the script? Is it holding the animator? Are you disabling it with animation?

Comment: why do you disable GameObject instead of Animator Component.do you have script attach to GameObject ?

Comment: @SP It's the parent. I'm disabling it through code, not with animation

Comment: @smkplus Yes. Plus I generally disable ui gameobjects when I don't need them cuz they're pretty unoptimized for mobile.

Comment: do you use Boolean for controlling Go Text Show? if you want reset position you can false Go Text Show instead of disabling

Comment: @smkplus as I said, having an activated UI that doesn't do anything is really bad for mobile performance. It has to be disabled.

Comment: @Milen could you just falsify Go Text Show and then disable it in the same function(or call a subsequent function that disables it)? It has 0 Exit Time and Transition Duration so it should return to Wait rather instantly, if I'm not mistaken, prior to being disabled.